# SQL Server - User that last entered a record

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I created a Database with vb.net on top of it. Users are entering records into the system and updating them. Is there a way to capture who entered or updated the database?

Example:

```
LastModifiedBy |  CreatedBy 
Joe Bob        |  Sally Joe
```

Comment: Of course there is. The problem is that we know nothing about your architecture. You mentioned the technologies used, SQL Server and VB.NET, but not how things fir together. For example, are you using the same connection string from the application to auth users to the db or are users logging into SQL Server via domain credentials mapped to SQL Server users?

Comment: how is the application designed to login to the database? do you pass on windows credentials to the db, or do you have a generic user that signs into the db and gets/sets data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a predefined username and password in the connection string, your options are limited to the .NET side.  Through the database you'll have access to what machine name the update/insert/delete was executed from, but NOT what user. SYSTEM_USER will always return the account specified in the connection string.

If you truly need access to the Windows username of the person running your app, you'll need to update your VB.NET code to pass that as a parameter in with your queries and record it in some column.  This, combined with a history table, can give you a pretty comprehensive picture of who is changing data (outside of direct data edits through SSMS).

The `Environment.UserName` property is what you're looking for, and you can find more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: fyi current_user returns dbo if its a sys admin

Comment: Good note, thanks @MichaelRudnerEvanchik, I'll update to SYSTEM_USER

Comment: hmmm... looks like it gives the system admin every time. I am not having the users login via .net. I am giving them access through the DB only. the .net is just an executable file. If they have access to a folder and access to the DB they can use the app.

Comment: @user44565 in the connection string, are you using a UserName and Password defined explicity, or a trusted connection?

Comment: I see, I used in vb.net Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=SAdmin;Password=****")

Comment: Okay, that removes the idea of SYSTEM_USER being relevant.  i've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yep your prob correct. Now I just have to figure out how to do that

Comment: On a side note, if "SAdmin" = sysadmin privs, not good!

Comment: Agreed - big risk.  @user44565 it would be worth replacing that with a SqlServer login that has read/write to the tables you need but no more access than that.

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[audit_trigger] on [dbo].[table_name] for insert, update, delete
as
 begin

insert into audit(user,table,time_stamp) values (SYSTEM_USER,'table_name',getdate())
end
```

or create a field user in your table and make the default SYSTEM_USER

Comment: if the application logs in with the same user, this solution is useless.

Comment: if your on the LAN users should use Windows Authentication (not a hard coded user for everyone) and it would get the correct user. you also didnt specify you were doing such a thing, so this is useful for some people

Comment: if the application uses hard coded credentials, all users will appear as one to SQL Server regardless if they are logged in to a machine on the network.

Comment: I give access to the user through the Database. If they do not have access to through the DB then they cannot access. I am going to try System_user now.

Comment: doesnt look like the op is using hard coded @Jeremy when he said VB im pretty sure he using a win form app on a lan

Comment: also, this will not tell which records were updated or modified. just that they were at a specific time. It may be good enough for the OP, but usually if I need this, I have extra fields in the table, and update the modified_by field of the records affected.

Comment: he didnt ask for the row, he asked for the database, which assuming is table. i could code if it was an insert or delete or update, add a timestamp, get the id of the table, but my other option of the default for a new column of SYSTEM_USER is another option, i cant do everything for the OP and nor am i inside his head like you seem to be

Comment: hence my use of the word "if"

Comment: "user that last entered a record" is the title

Comment: record indicates needing to know which row was updated by whom :)